# Designing/debugging complex data binding graphs in polymer

Tags: polymer

As far as I can tell, most of the talks and resources on Polymer cover fairly trivial cases of data binding.

However, Polymer is a powerful tool that can in principle be used to build things like IDEs, WYSIWYG editors, or even simple games; as long as the total number of elements on the page is kept fairly small (certainly <1000, but  ideally <100).

However, in these examples, the graph of data bindings can become very complex, and the results of a single event (e.g. a mouse click) can propagate/reverberate around the binding graph in hard-to-comprehend ways.

So, the question is, firstly are there any resources (videos/blogs etc.) that discuss best practices etc. for these types of complex scenarios; and two is there any chance of having a tool which generates a graphical representation of the binding graph.  Ideally such a graph could be rendered in the page, superimposed on the elements themselves.  In fact, one could imagine having a "record" feature, that tracked data propagation during an event and generated a GIF showing the data moving around the graph.

This may not be an ideal question for SO, but it didn't seem right as an issue on github either.

Comment: Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAW4YDLtPVs&list=PLNYkxOF6rcICc687SxHQRuo9TVNOJelSZ&index=12) on data flow from this week's Polymer summit:

Comment: @Maria - yes, I was at the summit.  That was one of the more in depth looks at binding, but it was still fairly trivial.  I'm interested in how to deal with greater levels of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

That's the reason why you should use an external state management framework such as `redux` for complex apps.
You can use the [polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux) behavior which is a simple behavior that allows you to interact with `redux`.

You basically split up your components in [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.dwkad8nps). The presentational polymer components are your leaf components that are unaware of `redux` and only take in data and emit events. The container components implement the redux behavior and dispatch actions for state changes and pass data to their childs (usually presentational components).

The state is stored globally and all the state modifications happen in reducers that you can easily unit test. The advantage is that you can use the [redux-devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to do `time travel debugging` and also visualize your [state as a graph](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/releases/tag/v2.8.0)

Comment: That certainly looks helpful, but having loads of events doesn't seem like idiomatic polymer..unless you just use the auto-generated prop change events ( registered when notify is true)...it also seems a shame to require that visual components always be paired with a logic component.

Comment: In reference to my second point, I remember the pagination component demoed in one of the summit talks (a non-googler guy showing off a women's shopping app). This component was both visual and logical.

Comment: What do you mean with "loads of events" ? The idiomatic way in Polymer is usually that data flows down via properties/attributes and data flows upwards via events.  The only difference when introducing redux is that you don't have to pass all the data along the DOM tree. The container elements allow you to subscribe to slices of the state tree that they are interested in. Also a container component can be both visual as well as logical but you should aim to have as many re-usuable visual elements and when needed a container component in between